# Why can't I see images

Tags: bug, images

I cannot see images on Stackoverflow. Either images posted by myself like the one below, or in other posts by others.

See this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535541/can-someone-show-me-what-a-good-dependency-matrix-looks-like-and-specify-why) and the image below :

> [image: Image is not showing !]

EDIT :
In the console of my browser, the image is not loaded.

[image: Failed to load the image]

Comment: Can you see any images or is it just the ones in your screenshot that are broken?

Comment: Are images like the SO and SE logos also missing?

Comment: I cannot see the image. If you cannot see it too, then join *NotShowingImagesClub* :)

Comment: What about all the other images? your user avatar, the site logo, the small glyph icons on the right?

Comment: No. the log of Stackoverflow on the upper left corner and my avatar are showing correctly

Comment: Looks like images to an external site are not shown (part of the question), the images from SO itself are clearly there (the up/down arrow, the green tick, the user icon).

Comment: Just to make it clear for everyone: This is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535541/can-someone-show-me-what-a-good-dependency-matrix-looks-like-and-specify-why. I can still see the images.

Comment: Does a direct link work? http://i.stack.imgur.com/MlnfA.jpg is the first image. Perhaps your ISP / office / school / internet café is blocking imgur links?

Comment: @hdoghmen: your avatar and the logo are served from different domains.

Comment: I cannot see the image in this link : http://i.stack.imgur.com/MlnfA.jpg

Comment: Also see [Which browsers are officially supported? subtopic what else is needed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/158100)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you did not provide a link to the question:

Googling `insite:stackoverflow.com On this blog post Identify Code` led to this result: [Can someone show me what a good dependency matrix looks like and specify why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535541/can-someone-show-me-what-a-good-dependency-matrix-looks-like-and-specify-why)

I can still see the images from my corporate network, as well as over the guest network and LTE.

I suppose this is a client side issue. You should check your browser console for erros or blocked content. It might as well be your corporate firewall blocking imgur.com

Comment: I had that particular problem until I convinced our IT department to let images from i.imgur.stack.com get through. (Just tell let them know that they're essential to viewing any of the Stack Exchange sites, and if they're reasonable, they should comply.) I still have the problem with those few images that are still hosted by imgur.com directly, but those are getting fewer and farther between and are usually accessed by links put in by askers/answerers who don't know better.

Answer (score 7):

Since you cannot see the image via a direct link, this means that the issue lies on the side of your internet connection. Most commonly, this is a school or corporate firewall that blocks `*.imgur.com`. Ask your system administrator if you believe that accessing Stack Overflow and seeing images is necessary for your work.

Comment: Tldr is that imgur has a porn problem, so IT providers tend to block it. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109975/hosting-options-for-people-that-have-imgur-blocked-by-their-isp for more details and workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and the reason was that corporate network rejected to access the server where images where hosted.

it is definitely client side problem.